# Displaying mongoose objects on ejs page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I am using Node/Express and mongoose to build an app. I am creating 'Photo' objects in my database (schema shown below) which is basically just an image object.

```
var PhotoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
    name: String
});
```

I can successfully upload and create photo objects and now I am creating an /images view where I want to extract every photo object and render it as an image. I am using ejs for my views. After doing some googling I hav come up with the following for my images.ejs file :

```
<% photos.forEach(function(photo){ %>
    <img src="/img/<%=photo._id%>" >
<% }) %>
```

When I load /images it says "photos is not defined".

This is the first time I have tried to directly extract mongoose objects onto an ejs page - is there something else I need to do/include so that my function understands I am referring to the photo objects in my database?

I also have the following routes:

```
router.get('/img', function (req, res, next) {
try {
    Photo.findOne({}, function (err, doc) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        if (doc) {
            res.contentType(doc.image.contentType);
            res.send(doc.image.data);
        }
    });
}
catch (e) {
    res.send(e);
}
});

router.get('/img/:id', function (req, res) {
try {
    Photo.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function (err, doc) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=3000000');
        res.contentType(doc.image.contentType);
        res.send(doc.image.data);
    });
}
catch (e) {
    res.send(e);
}
});

router.get('/images', function (req, res) {
try {
    Photo.find({}, function (err, doc) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.render('images', { images: doc });
    });
}
catch (e) {
    res.send(e);
}
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view variable is `images` (`res.render('images', { images: doc });`), not `photos`. Rename one or the other and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! So simple but probably wouldn't have figured it out on my own.